# Objective-c: expected identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier

I am a total newbie with objective C and IOS programming trying to follow along with a tutorial from a book by Nick Kuh.

The tutorial says to put the following code in the ViewController implementation file and it is returning the error: "Expected Identifier".

Have I typed something wrong or could it be a typo in the book?  I don't even know what an expected identifier means in this context so would appreciate any help as I am totally stuck.

The part of the code sample highlighted in red in Xcode is

`object:[self.gameModel];`  I bolded it below and SO put ** on either side.

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.gameModel = [[BJDGameModel alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleNotificationGameDidEnd:) name:BJNotificationGameDidEnd
                                                   **object:[self.gameModel];**
         }
         return self;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573278/when-to-use-brackets-and-when-to-use-the-period-in-objective-c Read this to see when to use square brackets.

Comment: my typo..There was an extra [ between object: and self.  Removing it fixed problem.  Thx!

Comment: Ah I was just typing the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleNotificationGameDidEnd:) name:BJNotificationGameDidEnd
                                                   object:[self.gameModel];
```

remove the square bracket before self.gameModel

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleNotificationGameDidEnd:) name:BJNotificationGameDidEnd
                                                   object:self.gameModel];
```